# "Set in" vs "Set to"

Tags: grammaticality

I came across a sentence while proofreading, and it sounds wrong to me but I don't have the knowledge to understand why.

> Set it ***in*** the OFF position

The following sounds more natural to me:

> Set it ***to*** the OFF position

But when I think about it, we would say "Put it ***in*** the OFF position" so why does "Set it ***in*** the OFF position" sound off to me?

"Set" has a definition of "to put", so perhaps I'm just not used to it, or perhaps it has something to do with direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Set it in the off position”, sounds correct. —- For exemple: “*To operate, remove the back of the camera and set it in the position shown in the photograph.*” https://books.google.it/books?id=9ycDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22set+it+in+the+position%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRzaKnqu_9AhUvg_0HHQePBO0Q6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22set%20it%20in%20the%20position%22&f=false

Comment: Can you give a bit more context about what the text is about? All of the options _could_ be correct, but might be appropriate in different situations.

Comment: _Set_ is a causative of _sit_ and a close synonym of _put_, indicating careful placement, often (as here) the placement of a dial on a meter or scale controlling a function. Which preposition one uses to refer to the placement depends on the metaphor one is using: _on_ a 2-dimensional surface, _at_ a place on a line or path, _to_ a new value on a scale, etc. If you know what metaphor you're using, you know what words to use.

Answer (score 1):

> "Set it in the OFF position"
> The following sounds more natural to me:
> "Set it to the OFF position"

The word “set” is one of the largest entries in the OED with 430 definitions: As far as verbs go, I haven’t bothered counting but there is going to be a lot.

The two main ones in question is whether “set” means

(i) “to make fixed” or

(ii) “to adjust to a given position”:

(i) is locative, (ii) indicates a motion.

If we are speaking of a switch:

"Set it **in** the OFF position" = make it fixed **when it is in** the off position

“Set it **to** the OFF position" = **adjust it by moving it if necessary,** to the off position.

As far as "Set it **in/to** the OFF position" is concerned, both convey clearly the idea of what should be done with the switch.

Comment: +1. If the bare "set" is read as the imperative "switch it on", then "set it in the OFF position" might even carry the opposite sense to "set it to the OFF position". The former tells someone to switch an OFF position ON while the latter tells them to unconditionally switch it OFF.